# Hard limit of a sequence defined by recurrence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

Given the sequence defined by
$$u_0=1\quad \text{and}\quad u_{n+1}=\frac{u_n}{|\cos(u_n)|^{\alpha}}$$

Numerically, it appears that for $\alpha=1$, $u_n^{\frac{1}{n}}$ tends to $2$, and for $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$, $u_n$ tends to $\pi$. However, I have no idea how to prove it.  And it seems very difficult to find all $\alpha>0$ for which the sequence converges.

Comment: Hint: the limit of a sequence of the form $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ with $f$ continuous (if it exists) is a fixed point of $f$.

Comment: With your indication, what exactly are you proving?

Comment: For a certain value $a=0.7335$, we get $\cos(u_1)=0$ and your recurrence blows up.

Comment: @GEdgar  I did not say that the sequence does not blow up for all α.